# Universal App - Only Update iPhone Version

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm currently doing a complete redesign of a universal app but the managers decided they want the iPhone version out first.  The problem is that because it is a complete redesign, the old code is not compatible with the new frameworks without putting a lot of effort.  So is there anyway for me to submit the update so that only the iPhone version is updated while the iPad version keeps using the old version?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Its my guess that if you did this the iPad people would get an update notice since it'll be installed on their iPad already and its perfectly fine to download iPhone apps to your iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will have to maintain both code trees in the one project and make sure that the iPad uses the old code and the iPhone uses the new code. This includes the old code using it's existing libraries etc. This sounds like a bit of a nightmare but I am sure it is achievable, it may be worth creating two distinct trees (read folders) in xcode to make the division clear...

Any time you have an update it will be available for all devices, so it may be worth putting in the notes that the update affects only the iPhone version.

Comment: you mean something like [if device = iPhone (use new code), else (use old code)]  ?

Comment: In theory yes but you would need to decide how you split your code at each point. Assuming the new version is a complete rewrite then essentially you would only need to add this comparison once in the app delegate to kick you off down the right path for the current device.

Comment: That's the option I was trying to avoid because some of the classes have the same names and the redesigned version uses ARC. So if I did this, the code would have to be hacked together.

Comment: You could just use a different prefix for class names, it may look slightly ugly but it should work while you transition over

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. Since it is a universal app, the update will be pushed to both the iPad and the iPhone when you release it to the store. There is no work around that will prevent the release from showing up for the iPad as well.

Answer (score 0):

If @Paul.s answer is not viable,  convert the universal target to that of iPhone only and update it in the AppStore and put an ALL CAPS appstore description asking the iPad users not to update.

Comment: no second thoughts about it. this is like a slightly better than the worst option (i.e., wait until both phone and ipad are good to be updated)